# Cannot add WebPart to master page using SP Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, visual-web-part

I've built a WebPart for a SharePoint 2010 site. I need to add it to one of its master pages (using SharePoint Designer), and when I select it from the WebParts menu I click it but I don't see it added on the design page...

Could you please tell me how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Brian

Answer (score 1):

Adding Web Parts to masterpages is not possible directly since you cannot add a webpart zone either to a master page. If you add Web Parts without a Web Part zone aka static Web Parts, you don’t get any Web Part benefits from it–they act like any other control.

One way of tweaking this would be by adding a custom (empty) contentplaceholderid. It can be created in the master page which can then be utilized by page layouts to insert the part.

Steps in SharePoint Designer 2010

1. Add a uniquely named content placeholder in your custom master page
   example:

`<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderCopyright" runat="server"/>`

1. Within a page layout insert custom content for the placeholder
   `<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderCopyright" runat="server"></asp:Content>`
2. Insert a web part using designer into the newly created area. If the same part is to appear across all pages using the layout, do not use a web part zone, simply insert the part directly into the area.